# Why do I get this error? What does this error mean?

Tags: python

I am working on a login system in python as practice and I keep on getting this error when I try to make a for loop..."Non-iterable value SignUp is used in an iterating context"

```
from SignUp import SignUp

userName = input("Enter a username: ")
userPass = input("Enter a password: ")

sign_up = SignUp(userName, userPass)

for user in SignUp:
    newData = open("data.txt", "a")
    newData.write(userName, userPass)
    newData.close()
```

What does this error mean and how can I solve it?

Comment: We don't know what `SignUp()` is or what it returns. Maybe you want: `for user in sign_up` — why else would you create `sign_up`?

Comment: I just realized that, ugh. Thanks!

Comment: It still gives me the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make `SignUp` class iterable. Depending on what `SignUp` class is meant for, you will need to implement `__iter__()` function inside your class.
[This](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-make-a-class-iterable-create-iterator-class-for-it/) link gives some examples of how to implement the same. `for` loop internally uses the iterator protocol and hence we need to use an object that is iterable.